Methods on finding Automorphism group on simply connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$.
Suppose $D$ is the unit disc and I want to find Aut$(D-\{0\})$ and Aut$(\mathbb{C}-\{0\})$.
My approach:
For the first automorphism group, I think immediately about Aut$(D)$ and if some how I can pick out all types of $\phi \in $Aut$(D)$ that omits $0$ and I am done.
I know that $\phi= a \dfrac{z-p}{1- \overline{p}z}$ for $|a|=1$ and $|p|<1$. It is clear that $z=p$ then $\phi(z)=0$. So $z\neq p$. And $\phi(0)=-ap$. And I think
$$Aut(D-\{0\})=\{\phi=a \dfrac{z-p}{1- \overline{p}z} ~:~ z\neq \dfrac{2p}{1+ \overline{p}p} \land z\neq p\}$$
Is this correct? Or I am completely off, if so how should one start on approaching this? Thank you!
